# Jquery replaceWith deletes the content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

On mobile and tablet, I need to replace the `<span>content</span>` with a `select/option` tag.

I'm not sure why this is not working, as the options deletes the content inside.

Any idea on how to make this select option tag wrap around my spans?

```js
var $window = $(window);
 var windowsize = $window.width();

  function wrapContent(){
    if (windowsize < 800) {
      $('.pick-country > span').each(function () {
        $(this).replaceWith('<option></option>');
      });
      $('.pick-country > option').wrapAll('<select class="country-list"></select>');

    }
  }
  wrapContent();
  $(window).resize(wrapContent);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="pick-country"> 
<div class="country">PICK A COUNTRY</div>

<span id="London" class="London hotspot">London</span>
<span id="CapeTown" class="CapeTown hotspot">Cape Town</span>
<span id="Beijing" class="Beijing hotspot">Beijing</span>
<span id="Tokyo" class="Tokyo hotspot">Tokyo</span>
<span id="HongKong" class="HongKong hotspot">Hong Kong</span>
<span id="KualaLumpur" class="KualaLumpur hotspot">Kuala Lumpur</span>
<span id="Singapore" class="Singapore hotspot">Singapore</span>
<span id="Mumbai" class="Mumbai hotspot">Mumbai</span>
<span id="Shanghai" class="Shanghai hotspot">Shanghai</span>
<span id="Sydney" class="Sydney hotspot">Sydney</span>
<span id="StPetersburg" class="StPetersburg hotspot">St. Petersburg</span>
<span id="SanPaulo" class="SanPaulo hotspot">São Paulo</span>
<span id="SanFrancisco" class="SanFrancisco hotspot">San Francisco</span>
<span id="Dallas" class="Dallas hotspot">Dallas</span>
<span id="NewYork" class="NewYork hotspot">New York</span>
<span id="Dubai" class="Dubai hotspot">Dubai</span>



</div>
```

Comment: Just so you're aware, you can't have `<span>` tags inside of a `<select>` tag. It isn't semantically correct and browsers won't render it properly.

Comment: @JoshuaWhitley - He is replacing the `span` for `option` tags before wrapping it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are replacing them with a blank option.

You could do the following:

```
$(this).replaceWith('<option id="' + $(this).attr('id') + '">' + $(this).text() +'</option>');
```

```js
var $window = $(window);
 var windowsize = $window.width();

  function wrapContent(){
    if (windowsize < 800) {
      $('.pick-country > span').each(function () {
    $(this).replaceWith('<option id="' + $(this).attr('id') + '">' + $(this).text() +'</option>');
      });
      $('.pick-country > option').wrapAll('<select class="country-list"></select>');

    }
  }
  wrapContent();
  $(window).resize(wrapContent);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="pick-country"> 
<div class="country">PICK A COUNTRY</div>

<span id="London" class="London hotspot">London</span>
<span id="CapeTown" class="CapeTown hotspot">Cape Town</span>
<span id="Beijing" class="Beijing hotspot">Beijing</span>
<span id="Tokyo" class="Tokyo hotspot">Tokyo</span>
<span id="HongKong" class="HongKong hotspot">Hong Kong</span>
<span id="KualaLumpur" class="KualaLumpur hotspot">Kuala Lumpur</span>
<span id="Singapore" class="Singapore hotspot">Singapore</span>
<span id="Mumbai" class="Mumbai hotspot">Mumbai</span>
<span id="Shanghai" class="Shanghai hotspot">Shanghai</span>
<span id="Sydney" class="Sydney hotspot">Sydney</span>
<span id="StPetersburg" class="StPetersburg hotspot">St. Petersburg</span>
<span id="SanPaulo" class="SanPaulo hotspot">São Paulo</span>
<span id="SanFrancisco" class="SanFrancisco hotspot">San Francisco</span>
<span id="Dallas" class="Dallas hotspot">Dallas</span>
<span id="NewYork" class="NewYork hotspot">New York</span>
<span id="Dubai" class="Dubai hotspot">Dubai</span>



</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

From [**JQuery docs on replaceWith()**](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/):

> The **.replaceWith()** method removes content from the DOM and inserts new content in its place with a single call.

So, you'll have to add the content manually on each interation of the replace:

```js
var $window = $(window);
 var windowsize = $window.width();

  function wrapContent(){
    if (windowsize < 800) {
      $('.pick-country > span').each(function () {
        $(this).replaceWith('<option>'+ $(this).html() +'</option>');
      });
      $('.pick-country > option').wrapAll('<select class="country-list"></select>');

    }
  }
  wrapContent();
  $(window).resize(wrapContent);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="pick-country"> 
<div class="country">PICK A COUNTRY</div>

<span id="London" class="London hotspot">London</span>
<span id="CapeTown" class="CapeTown hotspot">Cape Town</span>
<span id="Beijing" class="Beijing hotspot">Beijing</span>
<span id="Tokyo" class="Tokyo hotspot">Tokyo</span>
<span id="HongKong" class="HongKong hotspot">Hong Kong</span>
<span id="KualaLumpur" class="KualaLumpur hotspot">Kuala Lumpur</span>
<span id="Singapore" class="Singapore hotspot">Singapore</span>
<span id="Mumbai" class="Mumbai hotspot">Mumbai</span>
<span id="Shanghai" class="Shanghai hotspot">Shanghai</span>
<span id="Sydney" class="Sydney hotspot">Sydney</span>
<span id="StPetersburg" class="StPetersburg hotspot">St. Petersburg</span>
<span id="SanPaulo" class="SanPaulo hotspot">São Paulo</span>
<span id="SanFrancisco" class="SanFrancisco hotspot">San Francisco</span>
<span id="Dallas" class="Dallas hotspot">Dallas</span>
<span id="NewYork" class="NewYork hotspot">New York</span>
<span id="Dubai" class="Dubai hotspot">Dubai</span>



</div>
```

Comment: `$(this).replaceWith('<option id='+ $(this).attr('id') +'>'+ $(this).html() +'</option>');`

Comment: Yes, or $(this).replaceWith($("<option/>").text($(this).text()));

Comment: But you should set the `id` as the option's `value=""` property

Comment: value"" but my id has a call which scrolls to content . so I need to keep the id's

Answer (score 1):

You are not retaining the text of the original span or its ID value. Just add those to the appended elements using `text()` and `attr()`:

```
  $('.pick-country > span').each(function () {
        $(this).replaceWith($('<option/>').text($(this).text()).attr({'value': this.id, 'id': this.id});
  });
```

**JSFiddle:**  http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/vyyw59c2/11/

Or if you pref, using a function parameter to `replaceWith()` like this:

```
    $('.pick-country > span').replaceWith(function () {
        return $('<option/>').text($(this).text()).attr({'value': this.id, 'id': this.id});;
    });
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/vyyw59c2/10/

Answer (score 1):

replace this line:

```
$(this).replaceWith('<option></option>');
```

with this:

```
$(this).replaceWith('<option>'+$(this).html()+'</option>');
```

edit (options with ids):

```
 $(this).replaceWith('<option id='+$(this).attr("id")+'>'+$(this).html()+'</option>');
```

Comment: This does not retain the ID.

Comment: well, he can concatenate anything he wishes with this, like in:

$(this).replaceWith('<option id='+$(this).attr("id")+'>'+$(this).html()+'</option>');

but I recognize your solution is more elegant.

Comment: Just suggesting you complete your answer. :)

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this:

```
$('body').append('<select></select>');

$('.pick-country > span').each(function (elem) {
    $('select').append('<option>' + $(elem).text() + '</option>');
});
```

Comment: This does not create the `id` or `value` attributes (also required - see comments)

Comment: This is a start I'm giving him, now he just has to use $(elem) to get the attributes...

Answer (score -3):

Replace with replaces the entire content, rather than the tags.

You could do:

```
$('.pick-country > span').each(function () {
    $(this).html("<option>" + $(this).html() + "</option");
});
```

Which is retrieving all of the HTML within the span object and inserting option around it.

My original post incorrectly used HTML to parse through and find instances of span within the object, which is incorrect because span would not be part of the HTML returned.